# Creating a structure

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I used a tool for Minecraft 1.7 to convert a `.schematic` file to a `.java` one for importing the `.java` into my 1.8 mod. I fixed an unlocalized block name, but there are still some errors.

Maybe I'm asking too much but can anyone just make my code work so it generates structures?

```
/*
 *** MADE BY MRPONYCAPTAIN'S .SCHEMATIC TO .JAVA CONVERTING TOOL v0 ***
*/

package com.crazyhoorsecore.WorldGen;
import java.util.Random;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraft.world.chunk.IChunkProvider;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.feature.WorldGenerator;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.IWorldGenerator;

public abstract class Trap extends WorldGenerator implements IWorldGenerator
{
    protected Block[] getValidSpawnBlocks() {
        return new Block[] {
            Blocks.grass
        };
    }

    public boolean locationIsValidSpawn(World world, int i, int j, int k){
        int distanceToAir = 0;
        Block check = world.getBlock(i, j, k);

        while (check != Blocks.air){
            if (distanceToAir > 3){
                return false;
            }

            distanceToAir++;
            check = world.getBlock(i, j + distanceToAir, k);
        }

        j += distanceToAir - 1;

        Block block = (world).getBlock(i, j, k);
        Block blockAbove = world.getBlock(i, j+1, k);
        Block blockBelow = world.getBlock
                (i, j-1, k);

        for (Block x : getValidSpawnBlocks()){
            if (blockAbove != Blocks.air){
                return false;
            }
            if (block == x){
                return true;
            }else if (block == Blocks.snow && blockBelow == x){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Trap() { }

    @Override
    public void generate(Random random, int chunkX, int chunkZ, World world, IChunkProvider chunkGenerator, IChunkProvider chunkProvider) { }

    public void setBlock(World world, int x, int y, int z, Block block, int metadata)
    {
        Block b1 = world.getBlock(x, y, z);

        if(bisAir(world, x, y, z) || bisLeaves(world, x, y, z))
        {
            (world).setBlockState(x, y, z, block, metadata, 2);
        }
    }





    public boolean generate(World world, Random rand, int i, int j, int k) {
        //check that each corner is one of the valid spawn blocks
        if(!locationIsValidSpawn(world, i, j, k) || !locationIsValidSpawn(world, i + 6, j, k) || !locationIsValidSpawn(world, i + 6, j, k + 5) || !locationIsValidSpawn(world, i, j, k + 5))
        {
            return false;
        }

        k = k - 10;
        i = i - 10;

        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 0, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 0, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 0, k + 2, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 0, k + 3, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 0, k + 4, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 0, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 1, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 1, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 1, k + 2, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 1, k + 3, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 1, k + 4, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 1, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 2, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 2, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 2, k + 2, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 2, k + 3, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 2, k + 4, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 2, k + 5, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 3, k + 0, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 3, k + 1, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 3, k + 2, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 3, k + 3, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 3, k + 4, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 3, k + 5, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 4, k + 1, Blocks.stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 0, j + 4, k + 4, Blocks.stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 0, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 0, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 0, k + 2, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 0, k + 3, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 0, k + 4, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 0, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 1, k + 0, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 1, k + 1, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 1, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 2, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 2, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 3, k + 0, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 3, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 3, k + 2, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 3, k + 3, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 3, k + 4, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 3, k + 5, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 4, k + 0, Blocks.stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 4, k + 1, Blocks.stonebrick, 3);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 4, k + 4, Blocks.stonebrick, 1);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 4, k + 5, Blocks.stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 5, k + 1, Blocks.stonebrick, 1);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 5, k + 4, Blocks.stonebrick, 3);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 6, k + 1, Blocks.stonebrick, 3);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 6, k + 4, Blocks.stonebrick, 1);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 7, k + 1, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 7, k + 2, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 7, k + 3, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 1, j + 7, k + 4, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 0, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 0, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 0, k + 2, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 0, k + 3, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 0, k + 4, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 0, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 1, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 1, k + 1, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 1, k + 2, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 1, k + 3, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 1, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 2, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 2, k + 2, Blocks.tnt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 2, k + 3, Blocks.tnt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 2, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 3, k + 0, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 3, k + 1, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 3, k + 2, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 3, k + 3, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 3, k + 4, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 3, k + 5, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 7, k + 1, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 7, k + 2, Blocks.stonebrick, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 7, k + 3, Blocks.double_stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 7, k + 4, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 0, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 0, k + 1, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 0, k + 2, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 0, k + 3, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 0, k + 4, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 0, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 1, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 1, k + 2, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 1, k + 3, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 1, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 2, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 2, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 2, k + 2, Blocks.tnt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 2, k + 3, Blocks.tnt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 2, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 3, k + 0, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 3, k + 1, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 3, k + 2, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 3, k + 3, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 3, k + 4, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 3, k + 5, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 4, k + 2, Blocks.air, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 4, k + 3, Blocks.air, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 7, k + 1, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 7, k + 2, Blocks.double_stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 7, k + 3, Blocks.double_stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 7, k + 4, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 0, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 0, k + 1, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 0, k + 2, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 0, k + 3, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 0, k + 4, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 0, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 1, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 1, k + 2, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 1, k + 3, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 1, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 2, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 2, k + 2, Blocks.tnt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 2, k + 3, Blocks.tnt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 2, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 3, k + 0, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 3, k + 1, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 3, k + 2, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 3, k + 3, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 3, k + 4, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 3, k + 5, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 7, k + 1, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 7, k + 2, Blocks.double_stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 7, k + 3, Blocks.double_stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 7, k + 4, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 0, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 0, k + 1, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 0, k + 2, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 0, k + 3, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 0, k + 4, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 0, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 1, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 1, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 2, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 2, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 3, k + 0, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 3, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 3, k + 2, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 3, k + 3, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 3, k + 4, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 3, k + 5, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 4, k + 0, Blocks.stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 4, k + 1, Blocks.stonebrick, 3);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 4, k + 4, Blocks.stonebrick, 1);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 4, k + 5, Blocks.stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 5, k + 1, Blocks.stonebrick, 1);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 5, k + 4, Blocks.stonebrick, 3);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 6, k + 1, Blocks.stonebrick, 3);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 6, k + 4, Blocks.stonebrick, 1);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 7, k + 1, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 7, k + 2, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 7, k + 3, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 5, j + 7, k + 4, Blocks.stone_slab, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 0, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 0, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 0, k + 2, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 0, k + 3, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 0, k + 4, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 0, k + 5, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 1, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 1, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 1, k + 2, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 1, k + 3, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 1, k + 4, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 1, k + 5, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 2, k + 0, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 2, k + 1, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 2, k + 2, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 2, k + 3, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 2, k + 4, Blocks.dirt, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 2, k + 5, Blocks.grass, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 3, k + 0, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 3, k + 1, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 3, k + 2, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 3, k + 3, Blocks.stone, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 3, k + 4, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 3, k + 5, Blocks.stonebrick, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 4, k + 1, Blocks.stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 6, j + 4, k + 4, Blocks.stone_slab, 5);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 4, k + 2, Blocks.stone_pressure_plate, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 2, j + 4, k + 3, Blocks.stone_pressure_plate, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 4, k + 1, Blocks.stone_pressure_plate, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 3, j + 4, k + 4, Blocks.stone_pressure_plate, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 4, k + 2, Blocks.stone_pressure_plate, 0);
        this.setBlock(world, i + 4, j + 4, k + 3, Blocks.stone_pressure_plate, 0);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a loop is? You could easily simplify those 200 lines of `setBlock`s...

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before, lessons I learned:

- Don't export as a .java file. classes can only have a so much long length.
- That entire java file will reside in memory and will not really get cleared and will be incredibly sluggish.
- export to a friendly format, like nbt, json, yaml, your own, and read that.
- I use a json format

-

```
"blockids": {
       "1546678461":{
          "modid":"thaumcraft",
          "blockid":"blockCandle",
          "metadata":"14"
       }
    },
 "positions":[
       { 
          "blockpos":{ "x":10,"y":71,"z":-423},        
          "blockid":"1546678461",
          "isrange":false,
          "nbtdata":"something:something"
       },
       { 
          "blockid":"1546678461",
          "isrange":true,
          "from":{ "x":10,"y":71,"z":-423},        
          "to":{ "x":20,"y":71,"z":-413},        
          "nbtdata":""
       }
     ]
  }
```

- when coupled with zip export it's quite efficient
- when not using worldgen to initialise:

  - when loading json file that spans multiple chunks, split them up to the active chunks they will be "pasted" in
  - Then have a chunkloaded to actively load the chunk you will be pasting in currently
  - unload the chunk when pasted in.
  - load next chunk and paste taht bit in. Rinse and repeat for as big as your structure is
- prefably load your structures the minecraft way, so a nether fortress or a village won't generate through your structure.
- check for structures where you wish to generate.
- save your structures to the world map

-

```
protected StructureStart getStructureStart(int chunkX, int chunkZ)
    {
        MapGenEntropyTemple.Start start = new MapGenEntropyTemple.Start(this.worldObj, this.rand, chunkX, chunkZ);
        try {
            Class<?> mapgen = MapGenStructure.class;
            Method markdirty = MagicCookieReflectionHelper.getMethod(mapgen,"func_143026_a", int.class,int.class,StructureStart.class);
            if(markdirty != null) {
                markdirty.setAccessible(true);
                markdirty.invoke(this, start.getChunkPosX(), start.getChunkPosZ(), start);
            }
            else {
                MagicCookies.log.error("Structure generation locations cannot be saved.");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            MagicCookies.log.warn("well fiddlesticks",ex);
        }
        //this.func_143026_a(start.func_143019_e(), start.func_143018_f(), start);
        //Class c = MapGenStructureData.field_143029_e
        return start;

    }
```

- if you don't use the above saving method, the structure gen will not resume after user logs of and world is saved and memory is cleared.
- use MapGenStructure for your structures. Take a look at the nether fortress how it generates. You don't need a random approach as it uses, but you should use components like it uses for the individual parts, so you can define seperate bounding boxes.